# How to center Javafx stage

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, center, stage, locate

how to center locate javafx stage easily?

In swing, there it can be done by enabling generate in center.

But in javafx, how to center the stage.

Comment: That answer is not what I want. That's why I reposted. In there, it set by setting x and y. I want a simple inbuilt method to do it.

Comment: Or some property in scenebuilder